# maps in power BI: how bing resolve city names, world cities database?

Tags: maps, data-visualization, powerbi

I am running into an issue with Maps from Power BI.

I have a list of city name around the world in a different language than English.

[Excel containing distinct city name in Italian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2no8.png)

Using the visualizations Maps I get no feedback (i.e. map remain empty), so I started to translate the name into English, add country, state and continent. Nothing. The map remain still empty. I even change the data type of each column. NO-THING.
Finally I insert the Latitude and Longitude and then the visualization shows me what I want.

[Full geographics description database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBMBd.png)

1) Does anyone knows how bings works? I though it will to the best guess, but nothing happens till I insert the lat and long.

2) Does anyone knows about a database with the lat and Long of cities around the world?

Comment: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-tips-and-tricks-for-power-bi-map-visualizations/?cdn=disable

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 2): you can get lat/long via the Google Maps geolocation API. Make it a (paginated) function in Power Query and you'll be good to go. You'll need to create credentials in the Google developer console and if memory serves, the free tier is limited to 2,500 queries per day, so make sure not to query coordinates for the same city more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I found this database of latitude and longitude of major cities around the world.
It's a 40MB compressed txt file.

https://www.maxmind.com/fr/free-world-cities-database

Uncompressed file is about 140 MB of data, quite big for a power BI file.
I tried to load the entire file, and the pbix come out with 120MB.

Comment: The link gives 404